# How can I retrieve all the images from Resources at once?

Tags: c#, winforms, resources

I have added some images to the Project's Resources and I want to add them to a Bitmap List.
Looking at my code, it seems quite inefficient: I have to repeat the same code for 12 times.

How can I add them one-time?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<Bitmap> chineseZodiacList;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        chineseZodiacList.Add(Properties.Resources.猴);
        chineseZodiacList.Add(Properties.Resources.鸡);
        chineseZodiacList.Add(Properties.Resources.狗);
        chineseZodiacList.Add(Properties.Resources.猪);
        chineseZodiacList.Add(Properties.Resources.鼠);
        chineseZodiacList.Add(Properties.Resources.牛);
        chineseZodiacList.Add(Properties.Resources.虎);
        chineseZodiacList.Add(Properties.Resources.兔);
        chineseZodiacList.Add(Properties.Resources.龙);
        chineseZodiacList.Add(Properties.Resources.蛇);
        chineseZodiacList.Add(Properties.Resources.马);
        chineseZodiacList.Add(Properties.Resources.羊);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple method is to build a list of strings corresponding to the Bitmap names and load them in one go. Here, using your `List<Bitmap>`, but a `Dictionary<string, Bitmap>` (as shown in the second snippet) is probably better:

```
string[] zodiacSymbols = { "猴", "鸡", "狗", "猪", "鼠", "牛", "虎", "兔", "龙", "蛇", "马", "羊" };
List<Bitmap> zodiacImages = zodiacSymbols.Select(sym => (Bitmap)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(sym)).ToList();
```

Or, to get all resources of the type Bitmap (as in this case), you can use the [ResourceReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcereader) class and fill, for example, a Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, Bitmap> resImages = new Dictionary<string, Bitmap>();
```

which contains all the resources of type this and the resource name used as the Key:
(of course you can also filter by name - or anything else - not just ty Type)

```
using System.Reflection;

var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

using (var asmResStream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream($"{asm.GetName().Name}.Properties.Resources.resources"))
using (var resReader = new ResourceReader(asmResStream)) {
    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resReader) {
        if (entry.Value.GetType() == typeof(Bitmap)) {
            resImages.Add((string)entry.Key, (Bitmap)entry.Value);
        }
    }
}
```